# How to check what the value of app concurrent requests are in IIS

Tags: iis, concurrency

In step 4 of this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/951764?p=1) there is a description of how to set the maximum concurrent request in IIS throught scripts.

Is it possible to see what these values are set to, either through the IIS UI, or in the registry?

Note: This is for Windows 2008 and IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

The following are steps to SET it, but it occurs to be it might actually be shown in the textbox at the end...

1.
In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the application pool you want to configure, and then click Properties.

2.
On the Performance tab, select the Limit the kernel request queue (number of requests) check box.

3.
In the text box to the right of Limit the kernel request queue (number of requests), type the maximum number of requests to allow in the request queue, and then click OK.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, the link was to Windows 2008, but this was not clear in my question, your answer works for IIS6 but not IIS7. I have updated the question.